# Parallax UIScrollView – handling two views in one scrollViewDidScroll method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, parallax, uiscrollviewdelegate

I’m creating a basic parallax effect much like the iOS7 app switcher, using two `UIScrollView` instances (`cardScrollView` and `tileScrollView`). I scroll one alongside the other, at a different rate, like so:

```
if ([scrollView isEqual:self.tileScrollView]) {
    [self.cardScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((self.tileScrollView.contentOffset.x + 110) * TILE_CARD_DELTA,
                                                      self.cardScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
}
```

This works fine when scrolling `tileScrollView`. However, I’d like the same to work in reverse, meaning I can scroll `cardScrollView` and have `tileScrollView` move accordingly. The issue I’m having is that calling `setContentOffset` actually causes `cardScrollView` to call `scrollViewDidScroll` itself, meaning they’re continually trying to set each other at the same time, and all kinds of hell break loose.

Basically, the issue here is that both `scrollView` instances are relying on the same `scrollViewDidScroll`, and so I can’t differentiate between the two of them in there.

How can I get around this one?

Comment: If you want to do something like that you are going to have to set up manual panning and scrolling.  Having one view control another that can control the first view is basically a circular command.  One will set the other which will set the first which will set the second etc...  If you make a superview get touch events and make the scrollview's not userInteractionable you can achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Couldn’t I just assign one a different delegate?

Comment: Both delegate methods will still get called and try to adjust the other scrollview.  It's circular no matter how you do it.  You need one view that encompasses both scrollviews and can manually control their motion.

Comment: Why? They only call the delegate that I give them. If I give it a delegate in some other class, then report the changes back, it should be fine, no?

Comment: You finger scroll on one.  It's delegate method gets called.  It programatically scrolls the other.  The other's delegate method gets called.  It scrolls the first programatically.  There's nothing you can do about that.  You could create a super scrollview that controls the two, but one controlling the other controlling the first is not going to happen, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting reference of both in this method and work as per requirement :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

 {
   if (scrollView == self.tileScrollView) {
      // do something
   }
   else {
      // do something
   }
  }
```

Comment: Nope, this won’t work. The method is called first by one, then by the other, so both of those conditional cases will be hit every time.

Comment: @lukech..you told isssue is : Basically, the issue here is that both scrollView instances are relying on the same scrollViewDidScroll, and so I can’t differentiate between the two of them in there.....Can you tell your requirement again

Comment: Re-read the question, dude :) They both have the same delegate, so this `scrollViewDidScroll` is called by both, meaning if one scrolls the other, it’s a circular reference.

Comment: I read that @lukech ...can u show the code of scrollviewdidscroll and how u want that