# How to implement a tabbed page control

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I'd like to adopt a tabbed, sliding page control similar to the Beats Music app, where two dependent scroll views interact with each other to navigate through pages. In the beginning of the animation, I'm swiping left on the actual pages. When it scrolls really fast, I'm actually scrolling the tabs up above. This is similar to how iOS 7/8's multitasking app switcher works.

I've looked around, but can't find examples where the user can scroll both scrollviews. Usually just the content controller moves the tabs, like in this repo: https://github.com/daria-kopaliani/DAPagesContainer

I'm a little lost as to how I'd implement this myself. I can't just put two scrollviews on a container, and implement `scrollViewDidScroll` on both scrollviews because that would create a loop.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: looks like 2 scrollviews with paging enabled, when one scrolls, trigger the other to scroll

Comment: I didn't understand why you think it would create a loop.

Comment: @Segev, scrolling the top scrollview should scroll the bottom scrollview, and vice versa. My instinct was to just listen for scrolling activity in `scrollViewDidScroll` and adjust the other scrollview accordingly. However, when adjusting the other scrollview, the same delegate method will get called, and it will try to scroll the scrollview that the user is already interacting with. Make sense?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I don't think it's that easy. see my comment above.

Comment: @djibouti33 yes, the delegate callback tells you which scrollview was called. Check if its the one ur moving and ignore it

Comment: It _is_ two scroll views. Apple has explained in one of the WWDC videos (I think it was in 2013) how to implement this sort of thing. This is how the App Switcher interface is implemented, for example: a horizontal scroll view of app images, and a horizontal scroll view of app icons underneath. Watch they video, they tell you how it's done.

Comment: thanks @matt. I'll take a look. I browsed Session 217 yesterday, but they don't specifically cover the App Switcher (they do mention it though). I'll take another look to see if they cover a similar example. And just to be clear, I'm not denying that using two scrollviews is the solution...I was just questioning how to receive changes and update the other's contentOffset. thanks for the help.

Comment: "I was just questioning how to receive changes and update the other's contentOffset." Well I don't see what you think the problem is with that.

Comment: @matt this SO question is what got me concerned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756173/parallax-uiscrollview-handling-two-views-in-one-scrollviewdidscroll-method

Comment: @djibouti33 Yes. Sounds pretty easy to controller if I didn't miss anything from your explanation. Check out my answer.

Comment: thanks @Segev, working on it now. perhaps i was overthinking this all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a BOOL or a tag to identify who's the scrollview the user is dragging and by doing so control the other scrollview without looping back and forth.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.topScrollView.tag = 1;
    self.contentScrollView.tag = 2;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.scrollViewInControler = scrollView.tag;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView.tag == self.scrollViewInControler && scrollView.tag == 1)
    {
        //move contentScrollView accordingly
    }
    else //...

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    self.scrollViewInControler = 0;
}
```

I'm sure there are ways to perfect this but this is the main idea.